# Popping an alert when changing the drop down entry in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to pop up an alert message when a certain item gets selected in a drop down list in a column of my Google Sheets. After that I want to have two options in the alert message, continue selecting the value or cancel. I think I have to use onEdit() or onChange() functions, but not sure how to use them.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). You can do that with an `onEdit(e)` function. Make sure you are not asking an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Comment: Exact copy of [Popping an alert when changing the drop down entry in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/172942367).

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Are confusing two things - 1) the "popup" and 2) how to trigger the "popup". There are several kinds of `Dialogs and Sidebars` in Google Workspace Documents; a [Prompt dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs?hl=en#prompt_dialogs) sounds what you need, and the documentation includes a very good coded example. How do you initiate this? Not from a menu (as in the documentation example) but using `onEdit(e)` [Doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=en#onedite) as @doubleunary suggests.

Comment: Related: [Creating a Dialog Prompt Box from an onEdit Function isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62841779/1330560)